# Server 2012 Core (no GUI): Remote Server manager not working

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-command-prompt

I am trying <kbd>cmd</kbd> --> <kbd>MMC</kbd> --> <kbd>Server Manager</kbd> and then connecting to my Server 2012 no GUI

but i keep getting the following error The WinRM client cannot process the request

I am unable to upload images right now

This is not related to other post "How to Remote Manage Windows Server 2012 in Server Manager?" because title and description of that post is quite different from what i am asking

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://www.petri.co.il/2008-r2-server-core-enable-remote-management.htm

Comment: @ManuelFaux Thanks for the link but still no joy, i did followed the following msdn link mentioned by Glenn Sullivan unlike 2008 R2 there's no firewall option in sconfig in 2012 but i did disabled my firewall already  and i am still getting the same error message  Also I am able to open other thing using a remove mmc > like Windows Firewall, Computer Management etc but not server manager.

Comment: i update the title of the post saying server 2012 no gui

Comment: Microsoft calls this installation option "Server Core".

Comment: yes you are right, saying no gui makes it easy to distinguish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server core (server without GUI you are trying to access remotely), do:
`Configure-SMRemoting.exe –Enable` " in PowerShell, and
`winrm qc` in an Admin CMD Prompt.

Note this is assuming that you are accessing Server Manager running RSAT on Windows 8 or using another Windows Server 2012 (non-core) server manager.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574205.aspx#BKMK_1_5

Comment: now i am getting WinRM Negotiate authentication error need to investigate more on that

Comment: I wish i can give Up arrow point to this post but i am new user so not allowed , instead of the bottom one because this one was useful than the one below. The bottom answer didn't apply to 2012

Comment: Finally able to vote up.

Answer (score 3):

Have you run sconfig on the server and selected the option to "Allow MMC Remote Management" and "Enable PowerShell?"

This is a good guide:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/11/11/configuring-remote-management-of-hyper-v-server-in-a-workgroup.aspx

Comment: I did tried this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/11/11/configuring-remote-management-of-hyper-v-server-in-a-workgroup.aspx already but it's old and obsolete Allow MMC Remote Management is not present but i did enabled Configure Remote Management instead and followed the remaining steps and rebooted but no luck                                                   Enabled Windows powershell is also missing as i think it's enabled by default

Comment: Smells like maybe the firewall is on?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff firewall completely turned off for private public everything i can get to computer management using a remote mmc